# Tuples from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a problem in python codding. I need to get tuples from dictionary of keys with multiple values. For example from

```
my_dict = {key1: {value1, value2, value3}, key2:{value4, value5}}
```

i need to get

```
my_dict1 = {(key1, value1), (key1, value2), (key1, value3), (key2, value4), (key 2, value5)}
```

Comment: `my_dict1 = {(key1, value1), (key1, value2), (key1, value3), (key2, value4), (key 2, value5)}` is not a valid dict.

Comment: So... What would be the expected result of `my_dict1[key1]`?

Answer (score 4):

A simple comprehension would work:

```
my_tuples = [(k, v) for k, vals in my_dict.items() for v in vals]
```

Though the OP syntax describes a `set`, I'm not sure that is what was meant.

Answer (score 2):

```
tuples = {(k, vv) for k, v in my_dict.items() for vv in v}
```